# Find questions with bounty in grace period

Tags: support, bounties, expired-bounty

We can quickly see a list with questions that have an open bounty in the [Bountied](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) tab. But if a bounty enters the grace period, the question is not longer available in that list.

So, here's my question: Is there any way to see a list of questions with a bounty in its grace period?

Comment: Why would you need that list of questions?

Comment: @animuson Let say that I answered to more questions that now are in grace period. I want to find quickly those questions if I need.

Comment: Ehm, I don't think you need this. If you want to stay on top of it, then stay on top of it.  You don't need yet another folder; you already have lists of questions you answered, etc.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I thought that there may be is one trick like when I am searching for `user:me <string>` I can find all my questions and answers that contain `<string>`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `hasnotice:1` operator works for bounties in the grace period or not. I don't answer enough bounty questions to remember whether or not the banner still appears during the grace period.

Comment: @CodyGray You can add your comment as an answer. Indeed, searching for `hasnotice:1 closed:0`, I can find all questions that have a bounty (opened or in grace period), but which will include some extra posts with a notice (does not bother me too much that).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com) for bounties which were posted between 8 and 7 full days ago, so could be in their grace period. Since SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, we'll miss questions where the bounty has already been awarded later this week. Still, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1315772/bounties-potentially-in-grace-period) produces only 64 questions on Stack Overflow, and most of them are still in the grace period, so it's a decent method to get a list of questions with potential bounties in the grace period, at least in the beginning of the week.

The main challenge with SEDE queries for purposes like this is that SEDE will cache the results until the end of the week. However, it is possible to [break the cache](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325802/295232).

Comment: 64 questions is about 15%, so not really that accurate. Using the `hasnotice:1 closed:0` search also isn't very helpful as that returns close to 900 questions (on SO), so about 230%, however if you sort that list by activity you will most likely see the results with an active bounty or bounty grace period first.

Comment: 15% of what? I'm pretty sure there are less than 64 questions with bounties in the grace period, and the query results cover all of them (but include bounties which are already awarded). There *was* some other problem with the query (or at least the way SEDE treats it), thanks for making me double-check it.

Comment: It being 15% makes total sense btw, assuming bounties are distributed normally over the different days that is. As 1/8th = 15%.